# Dixon's Factorization Method Modulo Question

Tags: factoring

Looking at Wikipedia's [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_factorization_method) for Dixon's Factorization Method, it shows the following.

> We will try to factor N = 84923 using bound B = 7. Our factor base is then P = {2, 3, 5, 7}. We then search random for integers between `ceil(sqrt(84923)`, which equals 292 and N whose squares are B-smooth.

At this point, my understanding is that a number *x* is B-smooth if its factors only include P, which equals {2, 3, 5, 7} in this example.

> 513^2 mod 84923 = 8400 = 2^4 * 3 * 5^2 * 7 
> 537^2 mod 84923 = 33600 = 2^6 * 3 * 5^2 * 7

Is there any particular factorization that's used to get 8400's and 33600's factors?

> (513 * 537)^2 mod 84923 = (275831)^2 mod 84923 
> = (84923 * 3 + 20712)^2 mod 84923 
> = (84923 *3)^2 + 2 * (84923 * 3 * 20712) + 20712^2 mod 84923
> = 0 + 0 + 20712^2 mod 84923

Please explain the second, third and fourth lines. I don't understand the transition from the first to the second line.

> That is, 
> 20712^2 mod 84923 = (2^5 * 3 * 5^2 * 7)^2 mod 84923 = 16800^2 mod 84923
>
> The resulting factorization is 
> 84923 = gcd(20712 - 16800, 84923) x gcd(20712 + 16800, 84923) = 163 * 521

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To calculate
>   \begin{align*}
>   513^2&\mod 84923=8400=2^4\cdot 3\cdot5^2\cdot 7\\
>   537^2&\mod 84293=33600=2^6\cdot 3\cdot5^2\cdot 7
>   \end{align*}
>   there is *no particular factorisation algorithm* necessary, since we have a small factor base $P=\{2,3,5,7\}$ and we can take each prime and calculate in a *brute-force* manner  if and which powers of the primes in $P$ divide $8400$ resp. $33600$ evenly.

In the calculation below we apply some rules of *[modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)* and division of integers

\begin{align*}
  (513\cdot537)^2&\mod 84923\\
&=\color{blue}{275481}^2\mod 84923\tag{1}\\
  &=(84923\cdot 3+20712)^2\mod 84923\tag{2}\\
  &=(84923\cdot3)^2+2\cdot(84923\cdot3\cdot20712)+20712^2\mod 84923\tag{3}\\
  &=0+0+20712^2\mod 84923\tag{4}
  \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) note that $513\cdot 537=275481$ (and not $275831$)
- In (2) we use the *[Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)* $275481=q*84923+r$ with $q\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0\leq r<84923$ ($q=3$ and remainder $r=20712$)
- In (3) we apply the binomial theorem $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$
- In (4) we use

\begin{align*}
a^n\mod b&=(a\mod b)^n\\
(a\cdot b)\mod c&=(a\mod c)\cdot (b\mod c)
\end{align*} together with the fact that integer multiples of the modulus $84923$ are zero.

> **[2015-06-01]:** A small note according to OPs comment:
>
> The *[wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_factorization_method)* states at the  end of the *example* section
>
> \begin{align*}
> 20712^2 \mod 84923=(2^5\cdot 3\cdot 5^2\cdot 7)^2\mod 84923 \tag{5}
> \end{align*}

*Note:* This statement is some kind of *summary* of the calculations in the example above, since

> by some (presumably rather simple) algorithm we could find the prime factor decomposition of the randomly chosen values $513^2$ and $537^2$
>
> \begin{align*}
> 513^2&\mod 84923=8400=2^4\cdot 3\cdot 5^2\cdot 7\\
> 537^2&\mod 84923=33600=2^6\cdot 3\cdot 5^2\cdot 7\\
> \end{align*}
>   Therefore we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> &(513\cdot 537)^2\mod 84923\\
> &\qquad=(2^4\cdot 3\cdot 5^2\cdot 7)\cdot(2^6\cdot 3\cdot 5^2\cdot 7)\mod 84923\\
> &\qquad=(2^{10}\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^4\cdot 7^2) \mod 84923\\
> &\qquad={(2^5\cdot 3\cdot 5^3\cdot 7)}^2 \mod 84923\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
>
> We have already derived in steps (1) to (4)
>
> \begin{align*}
>   (513\cdot 537)^2\mod 84923=20712^2 \mod 84923\tag{7}
>   \end{align*}
>
> So, putting the RHS of (6) and (7) together gives the statement in wiki's example section.

Another view of the same thing is

\begin{align*}
20712^2&=(2^3\cdot3\cdot863)^2=428986944=5051\cdot84923 + \color{blue}{40871}\\
16800^2&=(2^5\cdot3\cdot5^2\cdot7)^2=282240000=3323\cdot 84923+\color{blue}{40871}
\end{align*}
Since both $20712^2$ and $16800^2$ have the same remainder $\color{blue}{40871}$ by division of $84923$, we observe

\begin{align*}
20712^2\mod 84923 &= 40871\\
16800^2\mod 84923 &= 40871
\end{align*}
or equivalently
\begin{align*}
(2^3\cdot3\cdot863)^2\mod 84923 &= 40871\\
(2^5\cdot3\cdot5^2\cdot7)^2\mod 84923 &= 40871
\end{align*}

Comment: In the final step of the wiki page: $$20712^{2}\mod 84293 = (2^{5}\cdot3\cdot5^{2}\cdot7)^{2}\mod 84923$$, can you please explain how the right-hand side was calculated? PS - thank you! I'll award 100 point bounty when it lets me.

Comment: @KevinMeredith: I've added a note in my answer according to your comment. Best regards,

Comment: That helped me - thanks. But, I do not understand the left to right conversion in bullet #5: $207122^{2}\mod84923=(2^{5}\cdot3\cdot5^{2}\cdot7)^{2}\mod84923$. I see [here](http://www.2dtx.com/prime/prime20712.html) that $20712$'s prime factors are: $2^{3}\cdot3\cdot863$.

Comment: @KevinMeredith: You're welcome and thanks for accepting my answer and granting the bounty. I've added some more information which should be helpful. Best regards,